# Dynamically adding routes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to dynamically add routes in my angular app

```
const routes: Routes = [
 // my static routes
];

let sections = localStorage.getItem('sections');

if (sections) {
  JSON.parse(sections).forEach(section => {
    routes.push({ path: section.route, component: SectionComponent });
  });
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

This works fine in dev but in a production build the dynamic route are not added. I have tried using a factory to make sure that the route are added but it fails build with a function call.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRouteFactory())],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I have also tried setting my section component as a default route which mostly works but when I go from one section to the other it doesn't trigger a route change and it stays on the first one.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: SectionComponent }
];
```

If I go to http://myap.com/firstsection it works fine.
Then if I go to http://myap.com/secondsection it stays on the first section even though the url changed.

If I then go to http://myap.com/oneofmystaticroutes then to http://myap.com/secondsection it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is somewhere in AOT.

My suggestion would be move route config to AppComponent.
Inject router and routes then append routes you need then try to use **resetConfig**

```
routes.push({ path: section.route, component: SectionComponent });
router.resetConfig(routes);
```

Comment: That seems to be so. The variables are stripped out in AOT. `router.resetConfig(routes)` workaround seems to be the only way right now. I've raised this issue on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6784). Hope we get a resolution soon.

Comment: do you know how to do the same for a lazy module? Doing a router.resetConfig in `lazy-loaded-routing.module.ts` resets the parent app-routing.module.ts route config.