# Angular: Setup routes depending on service method call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have route configuration set up via `@NgModule`. And I have a service that identifies what parts of the application should be shown for the user depending on certain conditions. I need to call that service and setup the routes according to the returned value.

**Problem:** Route configuration is setup inside an annotation and I can't get how to call the service in such setup.

To be more specific here is the example configuration I want to enhance.

My current routing setup:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'first-route',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'first-route',
        component: FirstComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'second-route',
        component: SecondComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    ...
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule {
}
```

The service that should change the route setup:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    getAccessibleRoutes(): Observable<string[]> {...}
}
```

**Question:** How can I make a service call and change the routes?

Note: I also looked on ["Dynamically adding routes in Angular"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233195/dynamically-adding-routes-in-angular) and ["How we can add new routes dynamically into RouterModule(@NgModule imports)"](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13860) but I haven't found clear answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understood your problem, I think you probably can consider using  route guards to reach you goal. I suggest you to use guards feature to specify the conditions of accessing your routes, instead of changing the list of routes.

Please check this link for more information about route guards:

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

I hope this will help you.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { YourSecurityService } from './your-security.service';

@Injectable()
export class YourRouteGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private router: Router, 
        private yourSecurityService: YourSecurityService) {
    }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

        console.log(state.url); // HERE YOU CAN GET REQUESTED ROUTE

        if (this.yourSecurityService.checkIfUserHaveAccess())
            return true;

        this.router.navigate(['your-route-to-redirect']);
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Next you should apply your guard to your route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'someroute',
        component: RouteComponent,
        canActivate: [YourRouteGuardService]
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Ho do I set `redirectTo` with router guards? For instance If I know that `first-route` is not accessible for the user I'd like to change the redirect to the `second-route`.

Comment: Please check an updated answer. Here you will find an example of how to redirect to another route in guard if your activation condition is not meet

Comment: @OleksandrShpota It looks like in your question your initial approach is to dynamically change the route configuration based on in-app logic. I would agree with Taras here that the more correct approach is to define your whole router configuration upfront and use Route Guards to limit accessibility to each route based on in-app data.See the Angular docs for more info https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules

Comment: @TarasIlyin but how do I know inside `canActivate` which route was initially requested?

Comment: @OleksandrShpota: I have updated answer for you. You can get requested route from incoming canActivate params. Please check the api reference of angular CanActivate interface for more details. Let me know if I can help you more.